# How can I generate a C# SDK from an OpenAPI

Tags: c#, openapi, visual-studio-app-center

Hi I'm using App Center for logging - they've got a web UI and also an API which looks to be OpenApi:
https://openapi.appcenter.ms/

How would I generate a C# SDK from this? I've tried using NSwagStudio

System.InvalidOperationException: The properties 'id', 'name' are defined multiple times.

Not sure why that would be the case because the webpage is showing this as a valid OpenApi spec

Comment: Can you not use the [Visual Studio App Center SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/wpf-winforms)? They have an SDK for a bunch of platforms. I assume you want the WPF/Winforms SDK as I linked to.

Comment: That's for logging errors, rather than retrieving them

Answer (score 4):

You might want to have a look at [microsoft/kiota](https://learn.microsoft.com/openapi/kiota/quickstarts/dotnet)